Given the height, width, and number of segments of an equally segmented arc, find the length of the segment and the angle of the first segment.
Problem
A shape has a base of width $w$. There is an arc whose ends are concentric with the ends of the base. The arc is segmented (inscribed) by $n$ chords of equal length. The height of the shape (not the arc) is $h$.
Given $w$, $h$, and $n$ (which entirely define the shape), find the length $x$ of the segments and the angle $\theta$ between the left-most segment and the base.
Examples
I think it is best to brake the problem down into two cases: (1) $n$ is even, and (2) $n$ is odd.
Case where $n$ is even

Case where $n$ is odd


Inscribe a regular $n$-gon in a circle of radius $R$ centered at $(0,0)$. The angle between consecutive vertices, measured at the circle's center, is $\theta=\frac{2 \pi}{n}$
Assume $(-w / 2,0)$ and $(w / 2,0)$ are two vertices, separated by $m$ sides (in your arc) . The angle between these two vertices at the circle's center is $\phi=m \cdot \theta=\frac{2 \pi m}{n}$.
The points $(-w / 2,0)$ and $(w / 2,0)$ define a chord of length $R$ so they satisfy $w=2 R \sin \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$ and therefore the radius of the cicle is:
$$ R=\frac{w}{2 \sin \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)} $$
Using the chord length formula with $\theta=\frac{2pi}{n}$:
$$x= \text { side length }=2 R \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$

The vertices of the regular $n$-gon can be written as:
$$
\left(x_k, y_k\right)=\left(R \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right), R \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right)\right)
$$
From that you can also find the angle you want using the cosine angle formula.

This doesn’t work. See the example images. The arc isn’t necessarily a semicircle, so the center doesn’t necessarily lie on the base. This depends on the height $h$ of the shape, which you didn’t take into account in your answer.
